# I can't get a shape to properly follow the path

Tags: animation, constraints, svg

I am trying to rotate the green rectangle following the circular path. Here is what I've tried so far

[image]

[image: trying to animate]

Why the rectangle doesn't rotate? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Whay did you do exactly? I don't see any keyframes in your Blend file.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka: Could you show me how to get tha thing to rotate?

Comment: You can change the forward axis to X.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka: I have tried all the possible combinations of those axes. but none is working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, when you hit "Animate Path" in the screenshot, there's a warning "Path is already animated!". But the only problem here is that you animated the path when the rectangle was off-center. So, the easiest way to fix this is:

1. Select the rectangle and reset its location (and rotation, but not necessary here) by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> for rotation).
2. Choosing the *Forward Axis* to either X or Y you can decide how the rectangle is oriented on the curve while *Follow Curve* is enabled (Z doesn't make sense in this case). Now the rectangle is back on the circular path.

With your current circle the starting point is the vertex located at 45° clockwise. If you want the rectangle to start at the screenshot's top position, you have to either rotate the circle 45° counter-clockwise in *Edit Mode* or select the top vertex and set it as "first point". The best way to do this is to have the *Curve Tools* addon enabled, select the vertex and choose "Set First Points" in the *Utilities* menu.

[image: curve tools]

Comment: Exactly, that solved the problem. I need to clear the location of the rectangle.

Comment: Sorry! I can't upvote since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Don't worry ;) Exactly the location was the key problem - and the _Forward Axis_. If you only reset the location and leave the _Forward Axis_ as Z, then only the connecting dotted line will move around the circle while the rectangle stays in the center. I edited the answer to slim it down to the main problems.

Comment: Now I want to upvote the answer a second time :D

Answer (score 0):

I removed the already existing constraint, I added a new one, set the `Target` to `circularPath` and it works as intended.

If you activate `Follow Curve`, the green square will "steer" along the curve :

`Follow Curve` is off

[image]

`Follow Curve` is on

[image]

Those are the settings I used

[image]

Comment: In my animation, you can see that I am checking `Follow curve` but nothing happens.

Comment: Just remove the constraint and add a fresh one using the settings I showed you and it will work. That's what I did.

Comment: In your animation, you set the forward axis to Z. You need to set it to X or Y.

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue at all, believe I tried this more than 30 times

Comment: By doing this steps you should get the square to rotate but it will have an offset in the rotation and as @Gordon said, you can fix this with `Alt` + `G`. Anyway, @Gordon's answer is the correct one as he explained exactly the origin of your problem.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka Actually it isn't even necessary to create anything new, so I edited my answer down to the main problems. By the way, you should swap your screenshots - the first shows "Follow Curve is off" and the second "Follow Curve is on"  ;)

Comment: Sorry about that. It's corrected now :).